# Docker: Route from container to hosts system localhost

Tags: docker, networking, localhost, containers

I am using docker-compose to build environment and I want to connect from running docker container to localhost on host system running docker. IE, I am on windows 10 where is running springboot app on 127.0.0.1:8080 and there is docker toolbox, which run container supposed to send POST to rest api on springboot app. I have found solution, when I send POST request to ip of my network interface, but I`m wondering, if there is any solution, where I will not declare any static IP (which can change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the host IP from inside docker container with this command

```
/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'
```